# Are inner transactions faster to execute than normal or (outer) transactions?

Tags: transactions

I googled this online, however, I can seem to find an answer for it. I would appreciate it if anybody can answer this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The concept of "inner" transaction is a bit misleading. There is only one type of transactions: an EOA (Externally Owned Account) who initiates a transaction which targets one address (contract or another EOA).

What is sometimes dubbed as an inner transaction is a part of a regular transaction which interacts from the first contract to another. So if your transaction targets contract A, and code in the contract A calls another contract B, the part about "A to B" is called an inner transaction.

Therefore it is executed inside the real transaction and it has no other speeds.